# understanding functions in Python (split, join, dictionaries)

Tags: python

I have this code:

```
def magic1(text, skip):
    return text[::skip]

def magic2(text, skip):
    return ' '.join(text.split(' ')[::skip])

def magic3(text, appearances):
    d = {}

    for w in text.split(' '):
        d[w] = d.get(w, 0) + 1

    words = [w for w,v in d.items() if v <= appearances]
    return ' '.join(words)

print magic1('abcdefghijklmnop', 2)
print magic2('hi bye doom boom', 2)
print magic3('hi bye doom boom doom bye bye', 2)
```

The first function return the string but with skipping on one letter. "ace..."
In the second function there's "' '.join" which enter space between each word, "split" returns a list of all the words in the string with spaces and again there's skipping. But why it was needed to use split and join together?
In the 3th function, "d={}" represent a dictionary. again, there's split, and each word in the string will be added in the dictionary. But I didn't understand this line:

```
words = [w for w,v in d.items() if v <= appearances]
```

every w in d.items will be in "words" if ther apperance is not bigger than 2?

Can someone help me please? **I use Google and docs**, **I'm just not sure If I understood this code.**
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**1)** *"...why it was needed to use split and join together?"*

```
In [1]: def magic2(text, skip):
   ...:     return ' '.join(text.split(' ')[::skip])
   ...:

In [2]: print magic2('hi bye doom boom', 2)
hi doom
```

The key part of this is the `[::skip]`. If this was excluded, the split and join would cancel each other out and the string would remain the same:

```
In [3]: def magic2a(text, skip):
            return ' '.join(text.split(' '))
   ...:

In [4]: print magic2a('hi bye doom boom', 2)
hi bye doom boom
```

However because we are skipping every second word in the list created by `.split(' ')` and then joining we get `hi doom`.

**2)** *"...every w in d.items will be in "words" if there appearance is not bigger than 2?"*

```
d = {}

for w in text.split(' '):
    d[w] = d.get(w, 0) + 1
```

This counts the number of words. We look to see if we have a value for `d[w]` already (and default to `0` if not) and then increment.

```
words = [w for w,v in d.items() if v <= appearances]
```

This then returns a list of words that appear less than or equal to `appearances`.

## Bonus

For the last part it would be simpler to use a [`defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#defaultdict-objects) that you can specify a default value for every key in your dictionary.

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(int)

for w in text.split(' '):
    d[w] += 1
```

Comment: First, thanks, but I still did not understand the second function. join and split are actually doing the same thing, no?

Comment: Join and split are doing the opposite things (joining with a `' '` and splitting every time there is a `' '`) and so, would cancel each other out. However, as in the first function, `[::skip]` is used. Breaking the line down we see `text.split(' ')` will return a list of words, `[::skip]` will then return our list without every second word (`new_list = ['hi', 'doom']`), and then we join each element with `' '.join(new_list)`

Comment: So join adds space between each word, and split deleats the spaces and put insted ","?

Comment: Join concatenates list elements to return as string. Split convert string to list and slice string on provided char as delimiter.

Comment: [`split`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) takes a string and returns a list of the words in that string that are separated by the provided delimiter. [`join`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) takes a list of words and joins them together with the provided character to output a string.

Answer (score 0):

Here you count the number of words:

```
d = {}

for w in text.split(' '):
    d[w] = d.get(w, 0) + 1
```

And here

```
words = [w for w,v in d.items() if v <= appearances]
```

you return words that occur `<=` than `appearances` (2).

In this list comprehension `w` contains a word, and `v` the correspondent value of a dictionary, the number of appearances. If this number is less or equal to `appearances`, `w` is included into the result of the comprehension. Thus you can only words with appearances less or equal 2.

Comment: So it's a dic that w is the word and v is how many times it occurs, right?

Answer (score 0):

This part of method creates dictionary which contains word as an key and integer as counter of occurences:

```
for w in text.split(' '):
    d[w] = d.get(w, 0) + 1
```

so it looks like this:

```
'bye' => 3,
'doom' => 2,
```

so this line:

```
words = [w for w,v in d.items() if v <= appearances]
```

iterates through dictionary set w to key of dictionary (word), and v for it's value (counter) and puts into words only that keys which occurences is greater or equals 2 :)